# how to decode cryptocurrency wallet with mnemonic phrases

Tags: wallet, mnemonic-seed

I want to create multi-coin wallet on Golang language and I faced with issue about how decode wallet with mnemonic phrases.

Answer (score 0):

> **how to decode cryptocurrency wallet with mnemonic phrases**
>
> I want to create multi-coin wallet on Golang language and I faced with issue about how decode wallet with mnemonic phrases.

The main use of mnemonic phrases in Bitcoin wallets is in [BIP-39 Mnemonic code for generating deterministic keys](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) but this has nothing to do with encoding of wallet data or with encryption of wallet data.

If you want to protect the privacy of wallet data, the normal approach is to use symmetric encryption (e.g. AES) of private keys using a wallet login-password as an encryption-key.

Golang has support for this in the standard `crypto` library, (e.g. `import (crypto; crypto/aes; crypto/elliptic; crypto/ecdsa)` etc).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but you mean, when I create wallets for user I need to crypto their and save to database?

Comment: @user125261: Your question didn't mention creating wallets for users. I was answering *"how to decode cryptocurrency wallet with mnemonic phrases"*

Comment: oh, yea, sorry) But anyway Thanks for help :)